# Finding indices of multiple items in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, search, matrix

I have an array of elements and I want to see the indices of them inside another matrix

For example, for

```
A = [1 2 3] 
B = [1 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 1 2 3]
```

then result array

```
C = [1 2 3 6 9 10 11]
```

that give the indices of 1 2 3

Is there any function or a short way to handle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want:

```
find(ismember(B, A))

ans =

    1    2    3    6    9   10   11
```